# Can you delete system32 with node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

1. On windows 7 and above is it possible to delete system32 with node and wreck the system?
2. Is the folder protected somehow?
3. Do you need to launch the script with admin permissions or something?
4. How would a code like that look like?
5. And if it's possible, is it also possible that a random npm package can contain such malicious code?
6. I've been kinda careless downloading npm packages, should I worry? Just curious, obviously :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes - provided your `node.exe` is running with Elevated permissions (aka "Administrative" permissions)
2. Yes, the folder has NTFS ACL permissions that require elevated permissions to delete, move and rename. Additionally the directory is Owned by [the built-in principal `TrustedInstaller`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2008/08/29/what-is-the-trustedinstaller-entity-you-see-in-windows-vista/).
3. Yes, as described in answer 1.
4. Invoke the [Windows command-line utility `runas`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.11).aspx). There is also an `npm` package which wraps this for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/runas
5. Yes, it's possible for a malicious `npm` script, or any Node script - or indeed any program at all, to make that call - however provided you have UAC enabled you will receive a full-screen prompt to confirm elevation.
6. No, don't worry - provided you have UAC enabled you'll always be prompted first.

Comment: 'No, don't worry' -> as usual unless there is some exploit somewhere to be used.

Comment: hmm, so system32 is protected. but what about different directories and files? i can delete some random file with a simple fs.unlink("C:\\Fraps\\im.dll"); - can't a malicious script basically search through my disk tree and recursively delete/overwrite my files?

Comment: @PingwinekPablo Yes, pretty much. A lot of modern computing is entirely built on trust. This is also how Ransomware works.